# Detect assertion failures in a helper method

Tags: c++, googletest

I would like to have a helper method in my tests that will cover some frequently executed checks. Consider this example:

```
void checkAsserts(int a, int b, int c) {
  EXPECT_EQ(a, b);
  EXPECT_GT(b, c);
  EXPECT_TRUE(isPrime(c));
}
```

The problem with this is that in the code later:

```
checkAsserts(firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal);
checkAsserts(X, Y, Z):
```

If the assert fails, I don't know in which helper. Ideally I would do this

```
ASSERT_TRUE(checkAsserts(firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal));
ASSERT_TRUE(checkAsserts(X, Y, Z));
```

However, the only way to achieve to that is to repeat every assert in the helper, which sucks:

```
bool checkAsserts(int a, int b, int c) {
  bool passed = true;
  EXPECT_EQ(a, b);
  passed = passed && a == b;
  EXPECT_GT(b, c);
  passed = passed && b > c;
  EXPECT_TRUE(isPrime(c));
  passed = passed && isPrime(c);
  return passed;
}
```

Ideally, what I would is something like this:

```
bool checkAsserts(int a, int b, int c) {
  AssertSentinel sentinel;
  EXPECT_EQ(a, b);
  EXPECT_GT(b, c);
  EXPECT_TRUE(isPrime(c));
  return sentinel.failures().empty();
}
```

Does gtest provide something like that? Or is there some other way I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got it correctly, you want to know which one of many callers causes test failures. [`SCOPED_TRACE()`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#SCOPED_TRACE) is for such purposes.

```
SCOPED_TRACE("");
checkAsserts(firstVal, secondVal, thirdVal);
SCOPED_TRACE("");
checkAsserts(X, Y, Z):
```

It will dump a file name and a line of the nearest upper scope trace if `checkAsserts()` fails the test case.

You can extend the scope trace with any useful message, as for me, the empty string is quite good for all cases.